# Как при авторегистрации записывать номер телефона в профиль (БИТРИКС)?

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день
На сайте стоит минимально кастомизированный компонент оформления заказа, пользователь заполняет 5 полей, одно из них телефон, но этот номер не сохраняется в профиле пользователя.
Попытался написать обработчик, но он у меня не сработал, почти не сталкивался с ними и с php у меня так себе
Вот что пытался использовать:

```php
<?
AddEventHandler("sale", "OnBeforeOrderAdd", "OnBeforeOrderAdd");
 function OnBeforeOrderAdd(&$arProps)
   {
    //  echo "<pre>";
    //  print_r($arProps);
    //  echo "</pre>";
    //  die();
    global $USER;
    $userID = $USER->GetID();
       $user = new CUser;
        $fields = Array(
        "PERSONAL_PHONE" => $arProps['ORDER_PROP']['3'],
        );
        $user->Update($userID, $fields);
   }
?>
```

Предполагаю, что в момент срабатывания обработчика пользователь еще не авторизован и не получается вытащить `$userID = $USER->GetID();`
В `$arProps['ORDER_PROP']['3']` хранится введенный в форму пользователем телефон
В настройках магазина Свойства заказ->список свойств->Телефон
стоит галочка входит в профиль, группа свойств "личные данные"

Comment: А если использовать дефолтный компонент все как надо работает?

Comment: Нет, да и кастомизировал я исключительно визуальную часть

Comment: А в админке у свойства телефон стоит галочка входит в профиль?

Comment: Да, специально проверял, думал это должно сработать изначально

Comment: Тогда советую писать в тех.поддержку.